# Xamarin.iOS: Security.SecSharedCredential.RequestSharedWebCredential crashing with "Unrecognized Selector"

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement some fairly basic/standard Xamarin.iOS code around sharing credentials between my iOS app and associated website.

```
public void TryGetSharedCredential(Action<Tuple<string, string>> callback)
        {
            try
            {
                Security.SecSharedCredential.RequestSharedWebCredential("www.jg.com", "me@jg.com", (accounts, err) =>
                {
                    if (accounts != null && accounts.Any())
                    {
                        var email = accounts[0];
                        var password = accounts[1];

                        callback(new Tuple<string, string>(email, password));    
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
        //log exception
            }

            callback(null);
        }
```

However, `RequestSharedWebCredential` crashes with the following log (and never enters the NSAction).

```
2017-10-02 16:33:30.083 JGMobileIOS[65076:4639965] -[__NSCFDictionary UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000282f40
2017-10-02 16:33:30.091 JGMobileIOS[65076:4639965] Xamarin.iOS: Received unhandled ObjectiveC exception: NSInvalidArgumentException -[__NSCFDictionary UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000282f40
2017-10-02 16:33:34.363 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical: Stacktrace:

2017-10-02 16:33:34.364 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical: 
Native stacktrace:

2017-10-02 16:33:34.365 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    0   JGMobileIOS                         0x0000000104938004 mono_handle_native_crash + 244
2017-10-02 16:33:34.366 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    1   JGMobileIOS                         0x0000000104945970 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 288
2017-10-02 16:33:34.366 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000011151db3a _sigtramp + 26
2017-10-02 16:33:34.366 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    3   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
2017-10-02 16:33:34.366 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    4   JGMobileIOS                         0x00000001049988bc mono_debug_symfile_lookup_method + 44
2017-10-02 16:33:34.366 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    5   JGMobileIOS                         0x00000001049fc87d lookup_method_func + 61
2017-10-02 16:33:34.367 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    6   JGMobileIOS                         0x0000000104ad75bd monoeg_g_hash_table_foreach + 77
2017-10-02 16:33:34.367 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    7   JGMobileIOS                         0x00000001049fc2f9 mono_debug_lookup_method_async_debug_info + 105
2017-10-02 16:33:34.367 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    8   JGMobileIOS                         0x000000010489bfbb ss_start + 331
2017-10-02 16:33:34.367 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    9   JGMobileIOS                         0x0000000104897b16 debugger_thread + 27910
2017-10-02 16:33:34.367 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    10  JGMobileIOS                         0x0000000104a4b283 start_wrapper + 675
2017-10-02 16:33:34.367 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011152f93b _pthread_body + 180
2017-10-02 16:33:34.368 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011152f887 _pthread_body + 0
2017-10-02 16:33:34.368 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical:    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011152f08d thread_start + 13
2017-10-02 16:33:34.368 JGMobileIOS[65076:4640005] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

I have tried:

- On simulator and device
- Without any linking ("Don't Link")
- Also tried the overloads that don't specify domain and account. According to the docs, if you pass a null domain, the domains specified in
  Entitlements.plist are checked. And if you specify a null account,
  then all stored accounts for that domain are supposed to be returned.
  Same crash.

I have checked entitlements.plist:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:www.jg.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:www.jg.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>`

I have the correct json at: www.jg.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association (on https)

```
{
  "applinks": {
    //applink stuff
  },
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
    //full teamid + appid
    ]
  }
}
```

I believe something is going wrong underneath the following Xamarin -> iOS api method mapping:

```
public static void AddSharedWebCredential (string domainName, string account, string password, Action<NSError> handler);

    public static string CreateSharedWebCredentialPassword ();

    public static void RequestSharedWebCredential (string domainName, string account, Action<string[], NSError> handler);

    [Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 8, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
    [DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security")]
    private static extern void SecAddSharedWebCredential (IntPtr fqdn, IntPtr account, IntPtr password, IntPtr completionHandler);

    [Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 8, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
    [DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security")]
    private static extern IntPtr SecCreateSharedWebCredentialPassword ();

    [Introduced (PlatformName.iOS, 8, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
    [DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security")]
    private static extern void SecRequestSharedWebCredential (IntPtr fqdn, IntPtr account, IntPtr completionHandler);
```

How can I get more details on what is going wrong? Am I missing anything and/or what else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

After working with a Xamarin Support Engineer, turns out this was a bug in Xamarin.iOS, and will be fixed in a future release:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60423

Fix committed here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/commit/03b9d1759e0bafe5d94d319e5a58f798a3ce575b